# I've encountered this kind of syntax: var == "" ? "-" : var. Can somebody explain?

Tags: php, syntax

The code is this one:

```
$vendors[] = array(
    "id" => $row['vendorID'],
    "name" => $row['name'] == "" ? "-" : $row['name'],
    "tel1" => $row['phone1'] == "" ? "-" : $row['phone1'],
    "tel2" => $row['phone2'] == "" ? "-" : $row['phone2'],
    "mail" => $row['email'] == "" ? "-" : $row['email'],
    "web" => $row['web'] == "" ? "-" : $row['web']);
```

Can somebody explain me exactly what it is? Look like an [Alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) but I haven't managed to find infos.

Thanks you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to `expr2` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` if `expr1` evaluates to `FALSE`.

Comment: might be worth mentioning that ternary operators are not unique to PHP - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 4):

It means: if value is "" (empty), then set  to "-" (hyphen), else set to whatever it is.

Just read a?b:c as «if a then b else c».

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is what the others say but it is not really recommended in terms of code readability. Use it with care and don't use it without brackets around the condition.

```
$myvar = ($condition == TRUE) ? $valueIfTrue : $valueIfFalse;
```

instead of

```
if ($condition)
{
    $myvar = $valueIfTrue;
}
else
{
    $myvar = $valueIfFalse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's what PHP insists on calling the "ternary operator" - see http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/language.operators.comparison.php for syntax and example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this like `"name" => $row['name'] == "" ?? "-"`

i.e a == b ?? c so if a=b is true use a else use c